api rest content to export array in body jspdf
I get the result of my rest api in angular in below format :
[
    {"city":"Texas", "Name":"John", "Company": "Nike", "ID": 1234}, 
    {"city":"New york", "Name":"Palmi", "Company": "Docker", "ID": 5678},
    {"city":"Alabam", "Name":"Dave", "Company": "Amazon", "ID": 0142},
    {"city":"Alabam", "Name":"Dave", "Company": "Amazon", "ID": 0142}
]

And i have a material table to display this table
<mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort>
 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>city</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.city}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Company">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Company</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Company}} </td>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 10, 15]" aria-label="List of employees"></mat-paginator>

This material table shows list of employees who must be exported to my pdf
public employeeList(){
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    autoTable(doc, {
      body: [
        [
          {
            content: 'List of employees',
            styles: {
              halign:'left',
              fontSize: 14
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      theme: 'plain'
    });

    autoTable(doc, {
      head: [['id','City','Name','Company']],
      body: [
        ['valFirstId', 'valFirstCity', 'valFirstName', 'valFirstCompany'],
        ['valSecondId', 'valSecondCity', 'valSecondName', 'valSecondCompany'],
        ['valThirdId', 'valThirdCity', 'valThirdName', 'valThirdCompany']
      ],
      theme: 'striped',
      headStyles:{
        fillColor: '#343a40',
      }
    });
    return doc.save("employees");
  }

How can I build my body with the result of my API rest in the format above with to add it to my body to replace this :
body: [
        ['valFirstId', 'valFirstCity', 'valFirstName', 'valFirstCompany'],
        ['valSecondId', 'valSecondCity', 'valSecondName', 'valSecondCompany'],
        ['valThirdId', 'valThirdCity', 'valThirdName', 'valThirdCompany']
      ]

